# sed on a ASCII-File with no line feed

Tags: bash, sed, ascii

I have an ASCII-Textfile with only one (long) line in it. I want to do a normal sed on it but nothing works. vi shows me with :set list that the line ends with an $
If i add a new line manually with vi the sed command works. If i do this:

```
echo $(cat file) |sed 's/.*test//g'
```

it does work too. Any idea why sed cant work with that?

Comment: Sorry, edited it. I just want to do a substitute

Answer (score 0):

The commandf `echo $(cat file)` is not going to preserve white space very well.

You should be able to add a newline, while leaving the rest of the file untouched, quite easily with:

```
( cat inputFile ; echo ) | sed 'something or other'
```

Just keep in mind that *some* `sed` implementations don't actually *like* very long lines. POSIX, I believe, mandated only a 8K minimum requirement. You should be okay if you're using the GNU variant, though.

Comment: Why use `printf "\n"` instead of a simple `echo` without parameters? Instead of a `(...)` subshell, command grouping with `{ ...; }` will work just as well